# How to calculate old date from current date in typescript or angular4+

Tags: angular, typescript, date, datetime, difference

How can i get the 90 days old date from current date in typescript or angular4

javascript function :

new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 6)

is not working in angular/typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an exmaple:

subtract-days.ts:

```ts
export function subtractDays(days: number, fromDate: Date = new Date()): Date {
    return new Date(fromDate.getTime() - (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
}
```

And in your angular component import the function and:

your-component.component.ts:

```
yourOldDate: Date = subtractDays(90);
```

Comment: cannot use const while declaring a variable in angular, it will give you an error message :
A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.ts(1248)

Comment: Im updatet my answer and moved it to a function so you can use it in your angular component.

Answer (score 1):

**This is reference for angular/typescript**.

To subtract a date from current date time, first need to get the time and then it needs to subtract the time difference you want it.

```
Example : if you need 90 days difference from current date

currentDate:Date = new Date();
currentDateTime = this.currentDate.getTime();
date = this.currentDateTime - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
oldDate:Date = new Date(this.date);
```